# ggplot2 divide Y-axis value without expand_scale()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to divide my y-axis by some value.
I used  `scale_y_continuous(expand_scale(add=2000))` but I got this message

> Warning message:
> `expand_scale()` is deprecated; use `expansion()` instead."

How can I get it to work?
Thanks!

Comment: It's just a warning right? Anyway you can use similar syntax https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expansion.html

Comment: thank you! I knew how to do it: use 'breaks=seq(a,b,c)' in scale_y_continuous function, 'c' is the range that we want to divide